# Statistics Discrete random variable question

Tags: statistics

I have a question and I don't know where to start, could you please help me?

```
At a computer store, the monthly demand for a particular
software package is denoted by the discrete random variable X which is assumed
to follow a Poisson distribution with λ = 10.
1. Find the probability that monthly demand for this particular software package is between 8 and 12.
2. What is the expected annual number of demand for this particular software
package?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. P( 8 <= X <= 12) = P(X=8) + P(X=9) + P(X=10) + P(X=11) + P(X=12)
2. E( 12X ) = 12*E(X) = 12 * $\lambda$ = 120

Comment: Could you please explain me the answer

Comment: part 1 is because we are working with a discrete random variable and the events are disjoint. part 2 is just using properties of expectation and then we know that E(X) for a poisson distribution is simply $\lambda$